# Tweepy: Trying to get data from Twitter

Tags: python, web-scraping, tweepy

I am trying to get data from twitter with python. I have the Twitter developer API, but I am getting None from the codes below. Is there anyone who can help with this issue?

Here is the API Key and Secret.

```
'''class TwitterAuthenticator():
    def authenticate(self):
        auth = OAuthHandler("*****", "*****")
        auth.set_access_token("*****", "*****")
        return auth'''
```

I used it to convert tweets to dictionary.

```
'''def get_tweet_dict(tweet):
    tweet = {"id": tweet["id_str"],
            "tweet_created_at" :tweet["created_at"],
             "text": tweet['text']
            }
    return tweet'''
```

This code takes tweets and returns them.

```
'''class TwitterListener(StreamListener):
    def __init__(self, limit, callback):
        super().__init__()
        self.limit = limit
        self.counter = 0
        self.callback = callback
        
    def on_data(self,data):
        t = json.loads(data)
        
        tweet = get_tweet_dict(t)
        self.callback(tweet)
        
        self.counter +=1
        
        if self.counter == self.limit:
            return False'''
```

It filters tweets by incoming keyword and language.

```
'''LANGUAGES = ["en"]

class TwitterStreamer():
    def __init__(self,keywords):
        self.twitter_authenticator = TwitterAuthenticator()
        self.keywords = keywords
    
    def stream_tweets(self,limit,callback):
        listener = TwitterListener(limit,callback)
        auth = self.twitter_authenticator.authenticate()
        stream = Stream(auth, listener)
        stream.filter(track=self.keywords, languages = LANGUAGES)'''
```

It is used to print tweets to the screen.

```
'''if __name__ == '__main__':
    twitter_streamer = TwitterStreamer(["messi"])
    print(twitter_streamer.stream_tweets(10,print))'''
```

It outputs 'None' after this code.

Comment: general debugging tip: print all your variables as you define them. In other words, see what your Twitter auth commands are returning.

Comment: I'm typing Twitter auth commands correctly. It throws an error when it's wrong.